# I want to solve the recurrence relation F(n,m) = F(n-1,m) + F(n,m-1) + 1?

Tags: recursion

I want to know how to solve a recurrence relation in 2 variables. I want to solve below relation:

```
F(n,m) = F(n-1,m) + F(n,m-1) + 1
```

Initial conditions:

```
F(m,0) = m

F(0,n) = n

F(0,0) = 0
```

Comment: Belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about “solving”.

Comment: Good starting point: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697731/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-with-sigma-notation-fn-m-fn-1-m)

Answer (score 1):

```
F(n,m)
{

  if (n==0)&&(m==0)
     return 0
  else if (n==0)
     return m
  else if (m==0)
     return n
  else
   return F(n-1,m) + F(n,m-1) + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir, but i want to know the Complexity of this program ?

Comment: I believe it is O(m)+O(n)

Comment: The Solution of this F(n,m) = F(n-1,m) + F(n,m-1) is (n+m)Cn

Answer (score 0):

Only parameters (≦ n, ≦ m) occur, one may exclude n or m being 0, so if you could hold a table of n×m that would be the optimal complexity: O(n . m).

One sees, that F(n - 1, m - 1) are both called, from F(n - 1, m) and F(n, m - 1), so a naive solution has a higher complexity.

Not wanting to spoil the joy of finding an algorithm, only some hints:

```
F(n, m) = F(m, n)   so you may use n ≦ m.

(table, result) = F'(table, n, m)    caching of results in recursive function
```

I personally sometimes like to start with an iterative non-functional procedure to fill a table, starting from 0 upwards. And then turn that into functional notation. For complexity an iterative procedure would already suffice.

Comment: I want direct equation of m and n so that I fill value of m and n and get output directly.